# Error in attaching/syncing many to many polymorphic relationship using Laravel

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, polymorphism

I have a Game class and a News class which can have many languages.

Here are my models:

```
Game:
id
string

News:
id
string

Languagable
id
languagable_id
languagable_type

Game:
public function languages()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('Language', 'languagable');
}

News:
public function languages() {
    return $this->morphToMany('Language', 'languagable');
}

Language:
public function games()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('Game', 'languagable');
}

public function news()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('News', 'languagable');
}
```

I followed the insertion or attaching/syncing that was instructed in this post:
[How to save entries in many to many polymorphic relationship in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896031/how-to-save-entries-in-many-to-many-polymorphic-relationship-in-laravel/23896998#23896998)

When I did:

```
$game->languages()->attach(1);
```

This error shows up:
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'language_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `languagables` (`languagable_id`, `languagable_type`, `language_id`) values (1, Game, 1))

It seems it's instead looking for another language_id instead of languagable_id. I've been at this for hours now and can't seem to get around this.

Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to add a language_id since it's a many to many relationship.