# Laravel many-to-many polymorphic relationships sql error while seeding

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many

Hello mine foreach loop returns a `Call to a member function bookmarkItems() on int`, when I try to seed mine database. I don't understand what I am missing [laravel docs poly relation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships) I have setup the relationsships like this and then when I am trying to save the new `bookmarkitem` is returns the error. [stack overflow post about saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896031/how-to-save-entries-in-many-to-many-polymorphic-relationship-in-laravel) I have tried `save` or `attach` but both return the same error I don't see what I am missing in the code.

Edit:

After seeing that `Post::all()->random()->id` should have beem `Post::all()->random()` it returns this error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'bookmarks_id' doesn't have a 
default value (SQL: insert into `bookmark_items` (`bookmark_items_id`, 
`bookmark_items_type`) values (5, App\Models\Post))
```

What means when attaching or saving the new bookmarkitem it doesnt add the `$bookmarkItems->bookmarks_id = Bookmark::all()->random()->id;` cause its not inserting that in the database while im setting it before saving the new bookmark item in the database?

Migration

```
    Schema::create('bookmark_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('bookmark_items_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('bookmark_items_type');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('bookmarks_id');
        $table->foreign('bookmarks_id')->references('id')->on('bookmarks');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Classes

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function bookmarkItems()
    {
         return $this->morphToMany(BookmarkItems::class, 'bookmark_items');
    }
}

class Comment extends Model
{
     public function bookmarkItems()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(BookmarkItems::class, 'bookmark_items');
    }
}


class BookmarkItems extends Model
{

    public function posts(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphToMany
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Post::class, 'bookmark_items');
    }


    public function comments(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphToMany
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Comment::class, 'bookmark_items');
    }
}
```

Foreach function

```
   foreach ((range(1, 6)) as $index) {
       $post = Post::all()->random()->id;
       $bookmarkItems = new BookmarkItems();
       $bookmarkItems->bookmarks_id = Bookmark::all()->random()->id;
       $post->bookmarkItems()->save($bookmarkItems);
   }
```

Comment: `$post = Post::all()->random()->id;` You're assigning just the ID to `$post`, not the actual post itself

Comment: Ah yes i see (oops) but now i get a differnent error ` General error: 1364 Field 'bookmarks_id' doesn't have a default value` it doesnt add `$bookmarkItems->bookmarks_id = Bookmark::all()->random()->id;` for some reason i updated the question

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from that bit of code? It's trying to insert `bookmark_items_id` and `bookmark_items_type`, which you don't have specified in the code you've shown

Comment: No its from the bookmarks_id but i found the problem ill post the awnser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

```
$post->bookmarkItem()->attach($bookmarkItem, ['bookmarks_id' => Bookmark::all()->random()->id]);
```

just had to give the additional data to be inserted like this `bookmarks_id`
so the end result would be like this

```
foreach ((range(1, 6)) as $index) {
        $post = Post::all()->random();
        $bookmarkItem = new BookmarkItem();
        $post->bookmarkItem()->attach($bookmarkItem, ['bookmarks_id' => Bookmark::all()->random()->id]);
}
```